# Get Count for each unique value in each Row in R

Tags: r, unique, rows

Given the following dataframe (read in from a csv file that I have no control over the contents)

```
          C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9
        1  a  a  a  c  d  b  c  c  a
        2  a  a  b  b  c  b  b  a  b
        3  a  c  c  d  d  b  c  b  b
        4  c  a  d  c  d  d  c  d  d
```

I need to get a count of each unique value in each row. If a single value appears 5 or more times, then that row should be determined to be invalid (possibly by adding an additional valid/invalid column). I do not care which value appears 5 or more times, just that any value does. In the above, rows 2 & 4 would be invalid. Unfortunately, I have no idea how many rows of data will be in the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to know whether the row contains more than four of any entry you can do:

```r
df$invalid <- apply(df, 1, function(x) max(table(x)) > 4)
#>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 invalid
#> 1  a  a  a  c  d  b  c  c  a   FALSE
#> 2  a  a  b  b  c  b  b  a  b    TRUE
#> 3  a  c  c  d  d  b  c  b  b   FALSE
#> 4  c  a  d  c  d  d  c  d  d    TRUE
```

If you actually want the counts for each row too you could then do:

```
cbind(df, t(apply(df[-10], 1,function(x) table(factor(x, levels = letters[1:4])))))
#>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 invalid a b c d
#> 1  a  a  a  c  d  b  c  c  a   FALSE 4 1 3 1
#> 2  a  a  b  b  c  b  b  a  b    TRUE 3 5 1 0
#> 3  a  c  c  d  d  b  c  b  b   FALSE 1 3 3 2
#> 4  c  a  d  c  d  d  c  d  d    TRUE 1 0 3 5
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also apply the `table` once if we make use of row index also as one of hte columns

```
cbind(df, as.data.frame.matrix(table(c(row(df)), unlist(df))))
#   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 a b c d
#1  a  a  a  c  d  b  c  c  a 4 1 3 1
#2  a  a  b  b  c  b  b  a  b 3 5 1 0
#3  a  c  c  d  d  b  c  b  b 1 3 3 2
#4  c  a  d  c  d  d  c  d  d 1 0 3 5
```

---

If we need to create the 'invalid' column

```
t1 <- table(c(row(df)), unlist(df))
cbind(df, as.data.frame.matrix(t1), invalid = as.logical(rowSums(t1 > 4)))
#  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 a b c d invalid
#1  a  a  a  c  d  b  c  c  a 4 1 3 1   FALSE
#2  a  a  b  b  c  b  b  a  b 3 5 1 0    TRUE
#3  a  c  c  d  d  b  c  b  b 1 3 3 2   FALSE
#4  c  a  d  c  d  d  c  d  d 1 0 3 5    TRUE
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = c("a", "a", "a", "c"), C2 = c("a", "a", "c", 
"a"), C3 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), C4 = c("c", "b", "d", "c"), 
    C5 = c("d", "c", "d", "d"), C6 = c("b", "b", "b", "d"), C7 = c("c", 
    "b", "c", "c"), C8 = c("c", "a", "b", "d"), C9 = c("a", "b", 
    "b", "d")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4"))
```